# Two finger iPhone scrolling

Tags: iphone, scroll

To mobile optimize a website, I have created a div with 'auto' overflow (CSS), so that the size of the div doesn't increase when the content does. 
For some iPhones, and iPod Touches, the only way to scroll such a div is with two fingers. I have tried an iPod of a friend on 4.2, he has to use two fingers. My own iPod (iOS 5.0.1), only needs one finger.

How to detect if the user has to scroll with two fingers, or with one? (If it's just a firmware issue, could you please tell me from which firmware you only need one finger, and whether this is iPhone, iPod or both?)

Answer (score 3):

iOS 5 provides 1 finger scrolling when an element has the following CSS property:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
```

iOS 4 can use 2 finger scrolling (which is near worthless since users don't know that they have this option) on elements that have, I believe, a set `height` and `overflow: scroll`.

Comment: Wooo... my full screen overflow:scroll bootstrap dropdowns now work.  Ty.